# Manually invoke validation of embedded form collection entries

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

In my Symfony project I have an entitiy `Booking` that contains a collection for another entity `Traveler`. There is a minum of 1 and a maximum of 4 travelers. The amount of travelers can be specified by a field `travelerCount` of the `Booking` entity.

```
class Booking {
    /** @Assert\Range(min = 1, max = 4) */
    private $travelerCount;

    private $travelers = array();

    // ...
}
```

My booking form controller always adds 4 travelers to the entity. My form `BookingType` contains an embedded form collection ([`CollectionType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)) for a `TravelerType` form. JavaScript in the view will show or hide travelers depending on the value of `travelerCount`.

Normally I'd use [`@Assert\Valid`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) to validate the traveler collection. But that won't work here, because I only want to validate the first *`travelerCount`* (1-4) entries of the collection. If, for instance, the user specifies a `travelerCount`of 2, I cannot validate `Traveler`s 3 and 4. Otherwise, there would be validation errors due to [`@Assert\NotBlank`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) annotations in `Traveler`.

```
class Traveler {
    /** @Assert\NotBlank */
    private $firstName;

    // ...
}
```

So my idea is to not use `@Assert\Valid`. But how can I manually invoke the validation of embedded form collection entries from the controller? I thought about something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $booking->getTravelerCount(); ++$i) {
    $this->get('validator')->startContext()
        ->atPath('booking.travelers['. $i .']')
        ->validate($booking->getTravelers()[$i]);
}
```

But I neither know if this will make the errors appearing in the view, nor which argument value to pass to `atPath()` (I just guessed above, but I'm sure I'm wrong).

Comment: what about creating a [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)?

Comment: I could do that, but it leads me to the same question: How can I tell Symfony to validate those entities? I could do the blank-check on my own and add violations manually, but I don't want to. I want to invoke the validation for the whole `Traveler` entity by its validation constraint annotations.

Comment: `@Assert\Valid` will validate all travelers based on the traveler constraints, and one of those constraints might be a custom validation which again can depend on the count of its parent booking. but to be honest i guess that's even not required here.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of my question, LBA suggested to use a custom validator and I told him that I have the same problem: I don't know how to invoke validation for the `Traveler`s validation constraint annotations. Well, I found out how:

```
class BookingValidator extends Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($booking, Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint $constraint)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $booking->getTravelerCount(); ++$i) {
            $this->context->getValidator()->inContext($this->context)
                ->atPath('travelers['. $i .']')
                ->validate($booking->getTravelers()[$i])
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the code looks similar to the one in my question. However, I didn't find a way to do this in the controller. But meanwhile I think having the validation in a separate class is better style, anyway.